# PHP fsockopen stopped working since 20/05/2022

Tags: php, azure, asynchronous, fsockopen

In our stack we need websites to be able to fire and forget a request to central server.
to do that we use a fsockopen. The code below has not been changed for years.

```
private function curl_post_async($url, $params = array()){
    $post_params = array();

    foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
        if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
        $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
    }
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

    $parts=parse_url($url);

    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
        isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
        $errno, $errstr, 30);

    $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
    $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
```

As you can see we are not using the while loop with fgets as we dont care about the response. We just need that data sent to central server.
We have not made any changes on any website or server in our network but as of Friday the 20th of May that function stopped working. We can get it to work by adding the while loop with fgets but that does not fit our requirements.

We have sites sitting on range of server and central server on Azure.

Interestingly enough the server it writes to has other apps on it. They also use this method and **it works still**.

Anyone got any input on this or seeing similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `fsockopen()` **may not work** because of **firewall restrictions** on **outgoing connections.**

In such cases, the port required for the outgoing connection should be opened. You can request this by opening a ticket through your

**`Client Area > Help Menu > View Help Center > Contact Us > Other > Report Other Technical Issues.`**

Comment: Thanks for your response. if we use fgets the and a while loop to wait for response the request is fired therefore i doubt its a port or firewall restriction. Also it worked for years and stopped out of nowhere.

Comment: It worked for years, but some of the authentications and approvals for the older packages. Based on the latest versions the validity of authentication will be applying. Replace PHP fsockopen with suitable alternative.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529680/non-blocking-alternative-to-fsockopen-in-php

The above link is to refer the non-blocking alternative for fsockopen